# Set a limit on checkbox and when it reaches the limit submit button will show PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, limit

i want to limit my checkboxes and when I reached to the limit the submit `button` will show, 
but once the submit `button` shows, and the user disabled one of the `checkbox`, 
the submit button will be disabled.

here's my code:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['lol'])){
  foreach ($_POST["lol"] as $pastry) { 
   if ($pastry=="cake") { //make sure the option they chose is part of the options :p 
    echo "<li>Cake</li>"; 
   } 
   if ($pastry=="pie") { 
    echo "<li>Pie</li>"; 
   } 
   if ($pastry=="cupcakes") { 
    echo "<li>Cupcakes</li>"; 
   } 
   if ($pastry=="brownies") { 
    echo "<li>Brownies</li>"; 
   } 
  } 
}
 ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

/***********************************************
* Limit number of checked checkboxes script- by JavaScript Kit (www.javascriptkit.com)
* This notice must stay intact for usage
* Visit JavaScript Kit at http://www.javascriptkit.com/ for this script and 100s more
***********************************************/

function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup
    var limit=limit
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount>limit){
            alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
            this.checked=false
            }
        }
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="test.php" id="poll" name="poll" method="post"> 
 <input type="checkbox" id='lol' name="lol[]" value="cake"> Cake :D <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id='lol' name="lol[]" value="pie"> Pie <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id='lol' name="lol[]" value="cupcakes"> Cupcakes ^O^ <br> 
 <input type="checkbox" id='lol' name="lol[]" value="brownies"> Brownies :D <br> 
 <input type="submit" value="Vote"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

//Syntax: checkboxlimit(checkbox_reference, limit)
checkboxlimit(document.forms.poll.lol, 2)

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ID's are unique in the document, and you can't have the same ID on multiple elements!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elems = $('#poll input[type="checkbox"]'),
    subm  = $('#poll input[type="submit"]').hide();

elems.on('change', function () {
    var limit = 2,
        _check = elems.filter(':checked').length;

    if (_check == limit) {
        subm.show();
    }else if (_check > limit) {
        alert("You can only select a maximum of " + limit + " checkboxes")
        this.checked = false;
    }else{
        subm.hide();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vY6wm/)

Comment: Of course, you will need jQuery for this, I didn't see it included in the OP code.

Comment: @Alex - the question is tagged with jQuery!